# Sql Server 2008: Issues while inserting the data into table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sap-ase

I am trying to insert a value in column in Sql Server 2008R2:

```
Create table Test
(
   Age varchar(3) NOT NUll
)

insert into test value ('030')

Output:
30
```

When i am trying same thing in Sybase:

```
 Output:030
```

Concern:
I need to keep '0' in Sql Server 2008R2 too beacause it is creating some formating issues in the generated output file.
Any suggestion how to retain that.

Comment: You should really correct the syntax in your question so it actually runs. I tried that on sql server 2008 r2 and it inserts '030' just fine, so the reason your leading zero is gone is not sql server. Maybe the tool you use for querying strips it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax for SQL2008 is a bit different, `{}` becomes `()` and `insert into [tablename] value ()` becomes `insert into [tablename] values ()`

so to make it works in SQL2008.

```
Create table Test
(
   Age varchar(3) NOT NUll
)
insert into test values ('030')
SELECT * FROM test
```

by the way why do you use varchar and not char?

Comment: Sorry! by mistake i put {} here, i am using () in sql server 2008R2,but facing the same issue. Actually, it is some premade scripts designed for sybase, so i am using same for the sql server.so, i dnt know why they use varchar and not char.

Comment: as @alun asked, are you using SSMS or some other tool. I tried in SSMS and returned 030

Comment: ok i just found out the ans.. i was getting 30 becuase i was putting 030 without quotes..but just wondering why it was not giving any error?

Comment: @Praveenks, can you please mark my response as Accepted? I'm starting to participate in Stackoverflow right now, I see that the gained points have impact on how I can participate.

Answer (score 0):

'030' without the quotes is just interpreted as the integer 30 by sql server. 
Also, when you try to insert an integer in a varchar field, it inserts it fine as varchar field accepts any alphanumeric value.
However, doing it the other way round might throw an error, as a varchar cannot always be converted to an integer.